# DRY up text parsing and ARGV

Tags: ruby, optimization, dry

Trying to iterate through multiple steps on a log file and append each step to a text via command-line input. I currently have working code but the problem is there is a lot of repetition of data as well as I'm having to create a method for each step, whereas I would like just one method able to iterate through steps one to... "infinity" if necessary, basically be able to take any number of steps that I shoot at it.

```
@log_file = "07-07-14 to 07-13-14_debug.log"

def s1
  File.readlines(@log_file).each do |line|
    if line.match /Recording dut_serial_number/
      File.open("step_one.txt", "a") << line
    elsif (line =~ /Beginning step #1 / .. line =~ /Beginning step #2 /) && line !~ /Beginning step #2 /
      File.open("step_one.txt", "a") << line
    else
      nil
    end
  end
end

def s2
  File.readlines(@log_file).each do |line|
    if line.match /Recording dut_serial_number/
      File.open("step_two.txt", "a") << line
    elsif (line =~ /Beginning step #2 / .. line =~ /Beginning step #3 /) && line !~ /Beginning step #3 /
      File.open("step_two.txt", "a") << line
    else
      nil
    end
  end
end
```

The goal is to be able to sort through each step as you see above by accepting command-line input as follows:

```
command_line = ARGV[0..1]

if command_line = "--step" + "1"
  s1
elsif command_line = "--step" + "2"
  s2
else
  nil
end
```

Comment: Is each step going to be doing the same thing, just to different data?

Comment: All steps are supposed to just parse through the text, yep!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your two routines are doing the same thing, it should be pretty easy to abstract a function that just takes a parameter for the thing you want to do. I also suggest using [OptionParser](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.1.2/libdoc/optparse/rdoc/OptionParser.html) instead of managing ARGV manually.

It appears to me that you could do something like this:

```
log_files = {1 => "step_one.txt", 2 => "step_two.txt"}

def read_log(step) #step is an integer
  File.readlines(@log_file).each do |line|
    if line.match /Recording dut_serial_number/
      File.open(log_files[step], "a") << line
    elsif (line =~ /Beginning step ##{step} / .. line =~ /Beginning step ##{step} /) && line !~ /Beginning step ##{step} /
      File.open(log_files[step], "a") << line
    else
      nil
    end
  end
end
```

This may not work, depending on your needs, but it may put you on the right track.

Comment: This is working pretty well with the code, but any direction you could point me in to make it where the code can accept any number of steps? Such as, the steps currently go to 7, but more might be needed to be taken out later, so basically where it can accept /any/ number as opposed to an arbitrary list.

Comment: Are the steps always going to be in order? i.e. 1-7, 1-20, etc